# How can I add an extra info bar at the bottom in excel?

Tags: c#, excel, toolbar, excel-interop

I'm searching for an option to create a custom infobar at the bottom just above the status bar in excel.

I want to display information. I've tried to use status bar for that but there is not much possibilities.

I can only show some text there. And that also can be changed by other excel's in-built functions.

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.StatusBar = "<Text Info>";
```

I was thinking to create a custom panel and make it fix positioned and always visible.

Any thoughts on this.?

Comment: Not sure whether this is possible. Maybe the experts can advise. I always use userform to display the status/progress

Comment: @manoj0790 can userform be docked at a fixed place?

Comment: you can set the position but cannot be docked like a status bar.